# How to generate an Info Message in the post build of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am working in Visual Studio 2013. I have written a console application that generates text. I call that application in the post build of another (larger winforms) application. I have been able to configure my output string in such a way that the output of my console application is picked up by Visual Studio, and is displayed in the error list. Hence if I call the console program in the other projects post build, in the error list of that project, I can see my output of my console application.

This works fine for errors, for warnings, but the third tab of that error view window in Visual Studio is the Messages/Info information. I cannot get anything in there. What should be the format of an info message?

```
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}({1},1,{1},2): {2}: test for error message {3}",    
                                                    "Test",
                                                    1,
                                                    "error",
                                                    "Test"));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}({1},1,{1},2): {2}: test for warning message {3}",    
                                                    "Test",
                                                    1,
                                                    "warning",
                                                    "Test"));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}({1},1,{1},2): {2}: test for info message {3}",    
                                                    "Test",
                                                    1,
                                                    "information",   // also tried info, tried message, it does not work.
                                                    "Test"));
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there a documented way to do that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26(v=vs.100).aspx